# How do I fix this ? [No Error Message]

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
  "Help" for details
    Help
    **<type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'><type 'int'>**
    >>> Help
    'for first and second values do, Color + Color'
```

When I run it the Bold message above would appear, However there would be no Error message and it would normalize after a second input

This is the Code

```
print ('"Help" for details')

Help = 'for first and second values do, Color + Color'

black =str(0) 
brown =str(1)
red =str(2)
orange =str(3)
yellow =str(4)
green =str(5)
blue =str(6)
violet =str(7)
grey =str(8)
white =str(9)



value = input ()


if input <= '10':
    print (str(int) * 10)
```

Comment: What is your purpose anyway? You want to create a docstring for a module?

Comment: Its a Resistor Color Code Calculator

Comment: @Turnip, Thanks for the Edit but I was already editing it after I saw my mistake

Comment: Well, what did you expect your program to print? What do you think `str(int)` is?

Comment: I think what you probably want to do is cast `input` to an `int` with `value = int(input())` and get rid of all the `str()`. But it's not clear what it's supposed to do, especially with `str(int) * 10`

Comment: @roganjosh str(int) * 10 works just fine

computing for resistor color code is like this
1. Get numerical values for color bands
2. 1st and 2nd ( or 3rd if 5 bands are present) would be the first and second digit respectively

Comment: Why should `str(int)*10` work in any useful way? Of course you will get `<type 'int'>` 10 times, `int` is a Python builtin, so it has no meaning other than to print the string representation of a builtin to create an integer type. If you're doing doing something like `int = 2` (which isn't happening in your code) then you're going to mess up the functioning of your script all over the place. It doesn't throw an error, but it gives a garbage result.

Comment: If you tried to input red + blue it would result to '26' which is an expected result ( also value = input () is supposed to have a # in the beginning )

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to do something like this. Keep practicing and don't give up. You'll get the hang of it eventually.

```
print ('"Help" for details')

Help = 'for first and second values do, Color + Color'

value = input ()

if value == 'black':
    value=0
    print (value * 10)
elif value==orange:
    value=1
```

etc